# How to use Xcode 6 to install two different iOS apps in a row

Tags: ios, app-store

I have developed two simple iOS projects. Now I want to make a relation between two projects. Like when I will install first project then automatically second project will be installed on iOS device.

How can I do so?

Comment: Are the two projects separate apps?  If so then you can create a bundle in itunesconnect as long as they aren't free apps. If they are free apps then they have to be installed separately

Comment: This is borderline on what's allowed, and what's prohibited. If your apps are paid apps, and you would like to **offer** them as a package, for say a reduced price, [App Bundles](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-bundles/) is the way to go. However, if you are expecting that your second app will be downloaded automatically, on installation of first app, then sandboxing does not allow that. The best you can do is prompt the user to download the 2nd app when they use the first app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't have the control to do something like this if I understand that correctly. You are trying to install an application first, then another application will be install automatically.

But, if you are thinking about creating relation between two applications, you can think about App Groups that can share data among the applications you specify. From the docs:

> Use app groups to allow multiple apps access to shared containers and
>   allow additional interprocess communication between apps. To enable
>   app groups, in the Capabilities pane, click the switch in the App
>   Groups section. You can select existing app groups from the table or
>   add app groups.

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually i don't want to make any relationship between two application.My target is only installed two application with two app icon anyhow through one  application installer.

Comment: ok ,but i did it for my android application by adding as a project another one.But I am totally fresh for ios development.Is it possible to make some different like forcing for installing another app.Or is it possible to check that another project is installed into device or not.If it is installed then ok,otherwise orce to user for installing another apps or auto installed.Something different.I think you can understand what i want to say.Please help me.It is so important for me.Ot give me a nice logical advice for making it perfect.

Comment: The differences between iOS and Android are huge. But you have to know that Android is actually open-sourced. In contrast, iOS does not. They just want to create a better ecosystem. And it seems like the advantage of doing this appears. For Android, there are many devices still in the API level 17 if I am correct. You can see why you can not do such thing. Vote it up if you like it, thanks.